# the relationship between two sequences in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just curious, if we have two sequences {an} and {bn} in a metric space, with one of them convergent to some limit, and the distance between the terms p(an,bn) is going to zero, is it necessarily true that the second one goes to the same limit? Can one be increasing and the other decreasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and yes. An example of the second phenomenon is the pair of sequences

$$\left\langle-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle\quad\text{and}\quad\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle\;,$$

which converge to $0$ from opposite directions.

The first result is pretty straightforward to prove using the triangle inequality. If $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $a$, and $\langle d(a_n,b_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$, where $d(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$, use the fact that $d(a,b_n)\le d(a,a_n)+d(a_n,b_n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_n \to \ell$. By the triangle inequality, $d(b_n, l) \leq d(a_n, b_n) + d(a_n, l)$, and since both of these quantities on the RHS of the inequality go to $0$, you can conclude $b_n \to \ell$.